# Angular slow ng-repeat: is there a way to refresh single items manually

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My ng-repeat takes 3.5 seconds to load 850 items:

```
<ol class="tasks">
    <li class="task-item"
        ng-class="{completed: task.isCompleted}"
        ng-repeat="task in (filteredTasks = (tasks | filter: search | orderBy:'order' | limitTo:1250))"
        data-order="{{task.order}}"
            data-id="{{::task.id}}">
        <div class="drag-handle color-1 " data-original-title=" "></div>
        <div class="title-container">
            <a class="title-link" ng-click="showTaskDetails(task)" ng-bind="task.title">
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="tree" ng-class="tree(task)"></div>

        <div class="check" ng-class="check(task)" ng-click="setCheck(task)"></div>

        <div class="actions">
            <a ng-click="setBucket(task, 1)" ng-class="{selected: task.bucketId === 1}" translate-once="MAIN_TOGGLEBUCKET_TODAY">T</a>
            <a ng-click="setBucket(task, 2)" ng-class="{selected: task.bucketId === 2}" translate-once="MAIN_TOGGLEBUCKET_TOMORROW">W</a>
            <a ng-click="setBucket(task, 3)" ng-class="{selected: task.bucketId === 3}" translate-once="MAIN_TOGGLEBUCKET_FOREST">F</a>
            <a ng-click="setBucket(task, 4)" ng-class="{selected: task.bucketId === 4}" translate-once="MAIN_TOGGLEBUCKET_GREENHOUSE">G</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I tried different improvements. I played with [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) library until I realized it was added natively to Angular 1.3. I started using [translate-once](https://github.com/ajwhite/angular-translate-once) to remove watchers from translated text. Still I experience slowness when loading 850 items. Is there a way to remove most of the watchers and repaint the UI manually per ng-repeat row (when I detect a change)?

Comment: Use track  by $index in your ng-repeat like:
<li ng-repeat="chosen in chosenlist track by $index">
You go through complete description here :
http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Comment: Try removing the filter and orderby and see how that impacts performance... I hear that is is pretty slow. If you post a plunker I can help debug.

Comment: make that 850 to lower by rendering only that can see on screen, or use angular-vs-repeat or If you have to show all of those, may be [my lib](https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA) can help, which replace angular rendering part, but pretty experimental lib. let me know if you want to try, your html need to adjust before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to display all at once, you can load 50 by 50.

```
<ol class="tasks" ng-init="lmt = 50">
 <li class="task-item"
    ng-class="{completed: task.isCompleted}"
    ng-repeat="task in (filteredTasks = (tasks | filter: search | orderBy:'order' | limitTo:lmt))"
    data-order="{{task.order}}"
        data-id="{{::task.id}}">
  ....
</li>
<li>
  <button class="btn-block btn btn-primary" ng-click="lmt=lmt+50">MORE.....</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remove most of the watchers and repaint the UI manually per ng-repeat row (when I detect a change)?

I'll go for some shameless self-promotion here and suggest you give [angular-bind-notifier](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier) a go.

To decrease the amount of watchers you would do roughly the following:

1. Convert all your bindings to onetime bindings with the `::` syntax.
2. Setup a notifier to watch a single property, exposed to the view (through `$scope`, or `this` in the case of controllerAs).
3. Pass in a `key` between the `::` in your bindings, to give them semi-static/semi-dynamic binding, based on the use of `$on/$broadcast`.
4. Either manually change said property when you want bindings to refresh, or leave it up to the outer world to manipulate the property and have the bindings refresh automatically.

It'd look something like so:

```
// In your controller/directive/whatever.
$scope.localisation = 'en';
```

---

```
// In your view
<ol class="tasks" bind-notifier="{ locale: localisation }">
  <li>
    <span>{{:locale:boundValue}}</span>
    <span ng-bind=":locale:boundValueTwo"></span>
    <!-- etc. etc. -->
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

I will say this though; I was under the impression that the original angular-translate `translate` directive had a built-in way of de-registering watchers when they become 'stale', but perhaps that is not the case.

---

*As the notifier directive is still in the early stages, your mileage may vary.*